# Deleting multiple directories(same name) in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, file-io, cvs

My team uses CVS. For some reason I need to create a shell script which deletes all folders with the name CVS(those who have worked on it might understand) present in my local copy.
Consider the super directory as ABC. ABC has different directories in it , which in turn contain directories named CVS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little change on previous answer:

```
find /path/to/ABC -type d -name "CVS" -exec rm -fdr {} \;
```

Comment: You should protect braces: `'{}'` or `\{}`.

Comment: you don't need to protect braces.. I've tried it.. it works

Comment: Maybe in this case not, but in general it's a good habit, see `man find` or http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/ABC -type d -name "CVS" -delete
```

Comment: This doesnt work.. its says invalid predicate '-delete'

Comment: Do you get all the directories when you run the command without -deletes